# await not working for firebase querySnapshot, next line executed

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have an async method to return the length of the documents of a firebase query with condition and o have implemented with await in the method. The code is below.

////////////////////////

```
getUreadMsgCount(groupChatId, id).then((result) {
    unReadCount = result;
    print("COUNT WITHIN getUreadMsgCount Method : $unReadCount");
});

print("UNREAD OUTSIDE METHOD : $unReadCount");
```

///////////////////////////////////////

```
Future getUreadMsgCount(String groupId, String idFrom) async {
    var respectsQuery = Firestore.instance
        .collection('messages')
        .document(groupId).collection(groupId)
        .where('idFrom', isEqualTo: idFrom).where('isSeen', isEqualTo: 0);
    var querySnapshot = await respectsQuery.getDocuments();
    int totalUnread = querySnapshot.documents.length;
    return totalUnread;
}
```

//////////////OUT PUT/////////////////////////

```
I/flutter (28972): UNREAD OUTSIDE METHOD : 0
I/flutter (28972): UNREAD OUTSIDE METHOD : 0
I/flutter (28972): UNREAD OUTSIDE METHOD : 0
I/flutter (28972): COUNT WITHIN getUreadMsgCount Method : 2
I/flutter (28972): COUNT WITHIN getUreadMsgCount Method : 0
I/flutter (28972): COUNT WITHIN getUreadMsgCount Method : 0
```

Here if you notice, it always executes the OUTSIDE METHOD line first hence always get with value as 0

I need to get the value from the method getUreadMsgCount initialized first then proceed with the next line. Any helps?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `await`:

```
var result = await getUreadMsgCount(groupChatId, id);
    unReadCount = result;
  print("COUNT WITHIN getUreadMsgCount Method : $unReadCount");
  print("UNREAD OUTSIDE METHOD : $unReadCount");
```

This way the code, after the asynchronous method call will get executed after retrieving the data.

The reason this:

```
getUreadMsgCount(groupChatId, id).then((result) {
    unReadCount = result;
    print("COUNT WITHIN getUreadMsgCount Method : $unReadCount");
  });

  print("UNREAD OUTSIDE METHOD : $unReadCount");
```

is not printing as you want, is because the method `getUreadMsgCount` is asynchronous, then the code after the `then()` method will be executed first and when the data is fully retrieved, the code inside the `then()` method will get executed.

https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#execution-flow-with-async-and-await

Comment: Great answer Peter. @MobDev: key point is that if you don't want to use `await`, then all code that needs the data must be *inside* the `then()` callback.

Comment: Peter, Frank Thanks for the answer, but another issue is the parent method is not async, hence I cannot use await when the method is called... How to handle forcefully wait for the response from the async function???

Comment: @MobDev I need to have an async function, the other way is just to add all the code that needs the data inside the `then()` callback as Frank said